# Why do I need to specify install rules for private targets?

Tags: cmake, cmake-export

I'm new to CMake and have trouble understanding how targets are exposed in the install interface. I have a CMakeLists.txt where I define two targets (PROJECT_NAME is "realtime"):

```
...
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} realtime_client.cpp)
...
configure_file(version/realtime_version.cpp.in realtime_version.cpp @ONLY)
add_library(realtime_version STATIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/realtime_version.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE realtime_version)
...
```

You can see that the `realtime_version` target is privately linked to the `realtime` target. For the install interface I just want the `realtime` target to be exposed to the outside world whereas the version target should vanish. So I would typically do this:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}_Exports"
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        COMPONENT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Runtime
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        COMPONENT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Runtime
        NAMELINK_COMPONENT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Development
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        COMPONENT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Development
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

set(REALTIME_TARGET_EXPORT_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}_Exports")
install(EXPORT ${REALTIME_TARGET_EXPORT_NAME}
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/realtime-${PROJECT_VERSION}
    NAMESPACE supabase::
    FILE ${PROJECT_NAME}_Development.cmake
    COMPONENT ${PROJECT_NAME}_Development
)
```

But then CMake complains that the realtime_version target has no install rules:

```
[cmake] CMake Error: install(EXPORT "realtime_Exports" ...) includes target "realtime" which requires target "realtime_version" that is not in any export set.
```

What I really want is for this library to just be compiled into the binary of the realtime target. I thought this would happen automatically, but it seems I'm mistaken. I might have missed a few essential things. So how can I hide the `realtime_version` target from export_sets and instead just compile it into the binary?

Comment: Is `realtime` static or shared? If static, then it doesn't embed other libraries, so files for both `realtime` and `realtime_version` libraries should be linked when one want to use `realtime` library. If `realtime` is shared, then it already embeds content of `realtime_version` library, so the latter doesn't need to be installed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ahh thanks for the explanation. Indeed, realtime is statically built, so I guess it always has to export the realtime_version header.